# Textinputs according to number of items in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, input

I have dyna;ic number of items in an array, and i should create text inputs to chnage these items, so how can i do it please ? any ideas ? I don't know how to use flatlist with text inouts.and how to handle every input, because the number is dynamic  I'm new to react.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component as item to render in the flatlist, and in the ItemComponent you can put anything,

Eg:

```
const ItemCard = ({...props}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Image />
      <TextInput />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Other component:

```
<FlatList renderItem={({item, index}) => <ItemCard />} />
```

Comment: but if i do like this, how can i handle every input independently ? if for example : my data is an array and i need to edit every item in that array ?

Comment: add a prop like onChangeText or onSave (and button save) or something else, with args like "newText", "item", "indexOfItem" and get done.

if the text is realTime sync best choice is onChangeText, but if there is save or submit like button , onSave is best option.

Comment: const ItemCard = ({onChangeText}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Image />
      <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => {if (onChangeText) onChangeText(text)}} />
    </View>
  )
}

<FlatList renderItem={({item, index}) => <ItemCard onChangeText={(text) => {/* you code */} />} />

An example for onChangeText

Comment: const ItemCard = ({onSave}) => { const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState('')
return ( <View> <Image /> <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => {setTextValue(text)}} /> <Button onPress={() => {if (onSave) onSave(textValue)}} /> </View> ) } <FlatList renderItem={({item, index}) => <ItemCard onSave={(text) => {/* you code */} />} /> 
An example for onSave

Answer (score 0):

```
nameofArray.map(
(arrayObject)=>
{
   <TextInput
    value={arrayObject.value}//here comes which value you want to disp
    />
}
)
```

If your data is large then you should consider flatlist

Comment: i don;t want to dsiplay , i have an array and the user may edit the names of the items in that array